# Large training and testing data in libsvm

Tags: python, c++, svm, libsvm

I'm using Libsvm in a 5x2 cross validation to classify a very huge amount of data, that is, I have 47k samples for training and 47k samples for testing in 10 different configurations.

I usually use the Libsvm's script **easy.py** to classify the data, but it's taking so long, I've been waiting for results for more than 3 hours and nothing, and I still have to repeat this procedure more 9 times!

does anybody know how to use the libsvm faster with a very huge amount of data? does the C++ Libsvm functions work faster than the python functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LibSVM's training algorithm doesn't scale up to this kind of datasets; it takes O(n³) time in the worst case and around O(n²) on typical ones. The first thing to try is scaling your datasets properly; if it still doesn't work, switch to

- a linear SVM (or logistic regression) using, e.g., [Liblinear](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/), [Vowpal Wabbit](http://hunch.net/~vw/) or [Wapiti](http://wapiti.limsi.fr/)
- a more scalable kernel SVM implementation such as [LaSVM](http://leon.bottou.org/projects/lasvm)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I use libsvm with linear kernel (for example -svmtrain with argument t 0), am I using a linear svm and thus the running time will be low?

Comment: @mad: no. You'll be using the same, slow, SMO algorithm. This is why LibSVM's authors released Liblinear, which can fit (almost) the same kind of model with a coordinate descent algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

As larsmans mentioned, libsvm may not scale all that well depending on the dimensionality of the data and the number of data points.

The C implementation may run a bit faster, but it won't be a significant difference.  You have a few options available to you.

- You could randomly sample your data to work on a small subset of it.
- You could project your data into a lower dimension with something like [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)
- Depending on your data type, you can look into different kernels.  Would a histogram intersection kernel work out for your data?  Are you using an RBF kernel when you really just need a linear decision function?

Hope this helps!  One of the toughest problems in machine learning is coping with the pure magnitude of data required at times.

Answer (score 0):

easy.py is a script for training and evaluating a classifier. it does a metatraining for the SVM parameters with grid.py. in grid.py is a parameter "nr_local_worker" which is defining the mumber of threads. you might wish to increase it (check processor load).